# C++ ofstream write in file from input, without new line after each word

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fstream, ofstream

Basically I have a function, that **writes** into a **.txt** file.
The **user** has to **input**, what will be **written in the file**.
The **problem** is, **every word has a new line**, even tho it's written in the same line, while doing the input.
But I want it to be the way the user inputs it.

```
    void Log_Write::WriteInLog(std::string LogFileName)
{
    system("cls");
    std::string input;
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open(LogFileName, std::fstream::app);
    out << "\n\nNEW LOG ENTRY: " << getCurrentTime()<<"\n"; // 
    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "Writing in Log\n\nType 'x' to leave editor!\n\nInsert new entry: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input == "x")
            break;
        out << input << "\n"; // How do I change this so it doesn't create a new line for each word
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Sample Input:

1st Input:Test Input

2st Input:Next input

Sample Output in file.txt:

Test

Input

Next

Input

**(Without the spaces in between!)**

Comment: `std::cin >> input;` just reads to the first whitespace while `std::getline(std::cin, input);` would read the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin >> input;` just reads to the first whitespace while `std::getline(std::cin, input);` would read the whole line.

One way of fixing it:

```
while(
    system("cls"),
    std::cout << "Writing in Log\n\nType 'x' to leave editor!\n\nInsert new entry: ",
    std::getline(std::cin, input)
) {
    if (input == "x")
        break;
    out << input << '\n';
}
```

I put the `std::getline` call last in the `while` condition to make the loop exit if `std::getline` fails.

---

Now, the above looks pretty nasty so I suggest putting clearing the screen and prompting the user in a separate function instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::istream& prompt(std::string_view prompt_text, std::string& line,
                     std::istream& in = std::cin,
                     std::ostream& out = std::cout) {
    std::system("cls");
    out << prompt_text;
    std::getline(in, line);
    return in;
}

void Log_Write::WriteInLog(std::string LogFileName) {
    // ...

    auto prompt_text = "Writing in Log\n\n"
                       "Type 'x' to leave editor!\n\n"
                       "Insert new entry: ";
    
    while (prompt(prompt_text, input)) {
        if (input == "x") break;
        out << input << '\n';
    }
}
```